# Tracking data with crashlytics Android

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

Sometimes, my application has errors due to wrong data. How can I know the details of that data when the application crashed with Crashlytics?

Answer (score 1):

Step1: Add Firebase to Your Android Project

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started#android

Step2: you can log caught exceptions in your app’s catch blocks:

```
try {
    methodThatThrows();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Crashlytics.logException(e);
    // handle your exception here
}
```

or

Step2: just call

```
Crashlytics.log(Log.DEBUG, "tag", "message");
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports#log_non-fatal_exceptions

after that, you are able to get your logs in firebase console

Answer (score 1):

**If you initialized Firebase** [Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=1#android)

when the application crashed all logcat information regarding crash uploaded to Firebase console

[image]

for customize your log

- Crash report and Log.println:

  `Crashlytics.log(Log.DEBUG, "tag", "message");`
- Crash report only:

  `Crashlytics.log("message");`

**In addition to automatically reporting your app’s crashes, Crashlytics lets you log non-fatal exceptions.**

```
try {
   methodThatThrows();
} catch (Exception e) {
   Crashlytics.logException(e);
// handle your exception here
 }
```

**All logged exceptions appear as non-fatal issues in the Firebase console**

[codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/?authuser=1#14)